# Correlation Matrix of Big Data

Tags: python, bigdata, correlation

I want to find the correlation matrix of matrix of size 503 rows × 278549 columns.
How can I find it  ?

I understand that I need a larger memory , so I tried google colab and google cloud But I could not calculate the correlation matrix.

I tried df.corr() on Jupyter with no luck.

Comment: 140,110,147 elements is a very big array. If this is an array of doubles (64-bit floats), that is 1,120,881,176 bytes. What are you using this for? (503 * 278,549 = 140,110,147).

Comment: How much memory do you have?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: I have 16 GB  and I need this data for genom analysis. How much memory do I need to perform this @256Bits

Comment: @sumaihal-hazzaa 1.1 GB, as I said. 16 GB should be more than enough. Are you sure the problem is lack of memory?